# CSS - how set style for buttons while input style is set?

Tags: css

I have these two in my html code:

```
<input class="input1" type="text" size="15" name="login">
<input class="input1" type="submit" value="Send">
```

In CSS I have styles for `.input1` and `input.input1`:

```
.input1 {
//something
}
input.input1 {
//something
}
```

And now I would like change style only for buttons (type submit) and keeps style for inputs type text. How can I do that? I tried in CSS with `submit.input1 {` and `button.input1 {` but this is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
input[type=submit] { /* your code here*/ }
```

or

```
input.inputbox[type=submit] { /* your code here*/ }
```

Comment: Note: IE6 won't understand this.

Comment: Thanks for help. Is there any other way to do that for IE6 as well (without js)?

Comment: @bazmegakapa True, as won't Netscape Navigator or Lynx, but we're not talking about mummies here (not referencing Lynx as a "mummy"). You are correct, nevertheless :)

Comment: @Lucas no solution that I know without butchering your code, but IE6 has 1.8% market share as of September 2011, and dropping. I'm not telling you how to go forward, but in my opinion, this Beelzebub-among-browsers should be left to succumb.

Comment: @George, it looks like we tied with our answers.

Comment: @George It's an old debate going on, nevertheless, projects still exist where you need to support IE6. Certain countries, certain audiences still have a high usage rate. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Lucas One possible solution is to add a common class to buttons, a common class to input boxes, etc. You can style based on them. But if your site's audience is not expected to use IE6 a lot, you could just use the **attribute selector** that George provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify attributes in selectors like so `.input1[type="submit"]`